# How an url with get variables can be a value of a get variable?

Tags: php, api, url, get

I want to use an API of a web-site. It works in a simple way. I specify URL and get the information that I need. In the URL, that I specify, I give URL of a web site about which I want to know the information. For example:

```
www.websiteapi.org?url=http://www.google.com&format=extended
```

I do not understand how API should work in cases where the URL (that I want to use as an argument) contains several get variables separated by `&`. In other words, how the API will know that sequence of symbols coming after `&` is part of the input URL and not an indication of a new variable that should be passed to the API?

What is a standard way to treat this situations?

**ADDED**

Here is an example how the API works:

http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?url=http://neatorama.cachefly.net/images/2007-08/iq-range-occupations.jpg&count=1

Comment: which API do you want to use? You have to read the documentation of the API if it supports an url with get parameters. Does url encoding work?

Comment: @KAOSFORGE What does the "url encoding" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[urlencode()](http://php.net/urlencode)

or even better,

```
$data = array('url' => 'http://neatorama.cachefly.net/images/2007-08/iq-range-occupations.jpg&count=1');
// or (depends on what url the count variable belongs to):
$data = array(
 'url'   => 'http://neatorama.cachefly.net/images/2007-08/iq-range-occupations.jpg',
 'count' => 1,
);
$url = "http://www.reddit.com/api/info.json?".http_build_query($data);
```

Answer (score 3):

You know about [URL encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL-Encoding)? That is, replacing special characters with `%` and their ASCII hex value.

Apply this to your URL and you're settled. Specifically, replace all occurances of `&` with `%26`.

On the server, the application splits incoming variables at the literal `&` and *afterwards* converts `%26` back to `&`. This is how you get the `&` sign (and other special characters like `#`) through an HTTP request.

Answer (score 2):

Count and URL are two parameters.

I would do this by replacing any `&` (and other characters used in urls, like `=` and `?`) using [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)